# How to pass a UserControl with CommandParameter?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, view

I have using a DelegateCommand and i want to pass the UserControl with Command.

```
#region OpenViewCommand
private DelegateCommand<UserControl> _openViewCommand;
public ICommand OpenViewCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_openViewCommand == null)
            _openViewCommand = new DelegateCommand<UserControl>(new Action<UserControl>(OpenView));
        return _openViewCommand;
    }
}

public void OpenView(UserControl ViewName)
{
    UserControl ctrl = (UserControl)ViewName;
    JIMS.Controls.Message.Show(ViewName.ToString());
}
#endregion
```

Command in XAML

```
<Button Name="btnStockGroups" Command="{Binding OpenViewCommand}" CommandParameter="JIMS.View.Stock.StockGroups">stock group</Button>
```

Comment: Why do you need access to the control in your ViewModel? The general MVVM appraoch would be to bind your control to the ViewModel and read data from the properties that it is bound to.

Comment: Is the OpenView command intended to cause a particular type of UserControl to be instantiated and shown to the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you give your UserControl an x:Name (e.g. "MyView"), you should be able to do something like this:

```
<Button Name="btnStockGroups" 
        Command="{Binding OpenViewCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyView}">
```

Comment: the element is not in the window.. its a UserControl file

Comment: How can you do it without naming the element?